# "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

SO is full of answers to this and they are all very consistent and they are all not working for me, so I'm missing something blindingly obvious.

Even when I tried to give up and use the hack of sticking `<script>var exports = {};</script>` before the call to `require.js`, I get "Uncaught Error: Module name "src/functions" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])"

Here's my minimal non-working example that seems most consistent w/ the other answers. I've also tried sticking `"type": "module"` everywhere I could think of.

What am I missing?

```
lib/
  - require.js
node-modules/
functions/
  - functions.ts
package-lock.json
package.json
test.html
test.ts
tsconfig.json
```

`src/functions.ts`:

```
export function consoleLog(msg: string): void {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

`test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="lib/require.js", data-main="test"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`test.ts`:

```
import { consoleLog } from "./src/functions";

function main(): void {
    consoleLog("foo");
}

main();
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain where you compile your ts files to? src folder?

Comment: I'm running `tsc test.ts` and `test.js` lands in the main folder and `functions.js` lands in `src/`